# The Name 'tabControl1' does not exist in the current context - Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, tabcontrol

I have ben searching this for over an hour and I can't seem to find an answer.

In the below code I'm trying to add a tab to a tabcontrol with a button.

```
    private void createTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string title = "TabPage " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
        TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
    }
```

I get two of the same error : The name 'tabControl1' does not exist in the current context.
I have a feeling I gotta link the tabcontrol up to the code but I'm not sure how.

I found the code at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984280%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Thank you for any answers.

Comment: You have not defined tabControl1 or else you have declared it within another method and not at the class level.

Comment: Does your tab control exist inside another container other than the form?

Comment: Yeah the tab control is in form1 whilst the addtab code is in form2

Comment: Thank you for your answer I have decided to keep things simple and keep everything on the same form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates that the "tabControl1" object doesn't exist within the same scope as the createTab_Click method.

If you're using Windows Forms, click on the control in the Designer and make sure its Name is tabControl1. If neither of these work, it's very likely that you've written the createTab_Click method in a different class than your main Window or Form class.

Based on your comment, you've indicated that you're trying to access tabControl1, which has been created on your first form, from your second form. This doesn't just work. You'd have to pass a reference to the first form to the second form, or pass the TabControl. You'd either need to do this after constructing the second form (using a public property) or you'd need to modify your second form to take the desired control as an argument, like so:

```
public Form2(TabControl yourTabControl)
{
    // all ctor logic goes here
}
```

and then instantiate that Form somewhere within your Form1 class, like so:

```
var form2 = new Form2(tabControl1);
form2.Show();
```

This seems overly complicated, particularly if you're just using one form to tab to another. It seems doubtful that your overall design will be helped out by doing this. If you'd like to keep the logic/content in any given Tab separate, I would break your code up into UserControls instead, and have those be the primary/sole Control within any given tab.

Comment: I'm using Windows Forms and Yes I have checked that :P

Comment: Did you define the createTab_Click method within your Form class?

Comment: Yeah I have made a form (form2) and im trying to add the tab from form2 whilst the tabcontrol is on form1. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your reply, the last comment was aimed at the answer

Comment: @Syntastic does this explanation help you out?

Comment: Thank you! I decided to keep everything simple and have the addtab on the same form.

Comment: That's probably the best option. If it was helpful, please don't forget to upvote (with the up arrow) and select the answer (with the check mark)!

Comment: Yes very much so thank you! sorry I think my command failed to post due to my slow internet.

Comment: sorry I cant upvote because I need more rep, I appreciate your help alot if that counts. :)